# how to stop app executing until AsyncTask has populated SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an app that calls a webservice and retreives a contentValue object. This object is populated with String String values that are to be stored eventually as SharedPreferences. I have used AsyncTask to make the webservice call as not to block the UI thread. The webservice does populate the CV object.

The problem lies when i try to use the values in the sharedpreferences. The shared preferences object is null. The app is trying to use this object before the AsyncTask has instantiated and populated it. How can i make the app wait untill the AsyncTask has finished?

CompID is a String that is passed to the webservice as a parameter. If when the app is first installed this variable is null i show a dialogbox to ask the user to enter the compID.

```
if(nfcscannerapplication.getCompId() == null || 
                                   nfcscannerapplication.getCompId().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("null")){ 
            Log.e(TAG, "compid null***********");
            showPasswordDialogBox();

        }
```

ShowPasswordDialogBox (not aptly named) gets the compID and passes it to asyncCompOpt().

```
public void asyncCompOpt(){

        String[] paramsCompOpt = new String[]{nfcscannerapplication.getCompId()};
        AsyncGetCompanyOptions agco = new AsyncGetCompanyOptions();
        agco.execute(paramsCompOpt);

    }
```

asyncCompOpt calls the AsyncTask.

```
private class AsyncGetCompanyOptions extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ContentValues> {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(EntryActivity.this, 
                "Connecting to Server"," Getting your company's options...", true);


    };      


    @Override
    protected ContentValues doInBackground(String... params) {

        ContentValues cv = null;

        try {
            Log.e(TAG, "inside doInBackground");
            cv = loginWebservice.getCompanyOptionsAndPhonenumbers(nfcscannerapplication.getCompId());

            if(cv == null){
                Log.e(TAG, "cv is null");
            }else{
                Log.e(TAG, "cv is not null");
            }




        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cv; 


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ContentValues result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(progressDialog != null)
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        String tagTouchInterval = (String) result.get("10"); 
        Log.e(TAG, "tagTouchInterval in onpostexecute = " + tagTouchInterval);
        String savePassword = (String) result.get("20");
        String allowChangeUser = (String) result.get("30");
        String displayRotaDetails = (String) result.get("40");
        String displayClientPhoneNumber = (String) result.get("50");
        String displayClientKeysafe = (String) result.get("60");
        String displayDoubleupCarer = (String) result.get("70");
        String displayContacts = (String) result.get("80");
        String autoLogout = (String) result.get("90");
        String displayNotesDisplayNotes = (String) result.get("100");
        String displayMeds = (String) result.get("110");
        String rotaLogout = (String) result.get("120");
        String displayActualTime = (String) result.get("130");
        String qrcodeEnabled = (String) result.get("140");
        String manualInput = (String) result.get("150");
        String rotasOnly = (String) result.get("160");

        appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(EntryActivity.this.getApplicationContext());

            prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit(); 

          prefsEditor.putString("10", tagTouchInterval);
          prefsEditor.putString("20", savePassword);
          prefsEditor.putString("30", allowChangeUser);
          prefsEditor.putString("40", displayRotaDetails);
          prefsEditor.putString("50", displayClientPhoneNumber);
          prefsEditor.putString("60", displayClientKeysafe);
          prefsEditor.putString("70", displayDoubleupCarer);
          prefsEditor.putString("80", displayContacts);
          prefsEditor.putString("90", autoLogout);
          prefsEditor.putString("100", displayNotesDisplayNotes);
          prefsEditor.putString("110", displayMeds);
          prefsEditor.putString("120", rotaLogout);
          prefsEditor.putString("130", displayActualTime);
          prefsEditor.putString("140", qrcodeEnabled);
          prefsEditor.putString("150", manualInput);
          prefsEditor.putString("160", rotasOnly);
          prefsEditor.commit();


    }//end of postExecute
```

I'll post a part of oncreate so you can see the flow of things. The app is trying to access the SharedPreferences before Async has finished. How can i fix this? thanks.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        nfcscannerapplication = (NfcScannerApplication) getApplication();
        sIs = savedInstanceState;


        if(nfcscannerapplication.getCompId() == null || 
                                   nfcscannerapplication.getCompId().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("null")){ 
            Log.e(TAG, "compid null***********");
            showPasswordDialogBox();

        }


        setContentView(R.layout.entryscreen); 

        //loginWebservice = new LoginWebservice(this);
        loginWebservice = nfcscannerapplication.loginWebservice;
        userName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        passwordPin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);



        String isSavePassword = appSharedPrefs.getString("20", null);
        isAllowChangeUser = appSharedPrefs.getString("30", null);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do what ever you need to do with the shared preferences in `onPostExecute()` instead if in `onCreate()`. If you like, disable the controls that you will update, or show a progress dialog, or something else in the mean time.

**Update:** And I should add that I have seen strange stuff with shared preferences. I have seen reads directly after commit that gives the wrong result. Don't use shared preferences as a way of communicating within your activity. Set (instance) variables and call callbacks instead.

Comment: thanks Do you think i'm using sharedpreferences incorrectly? The nature of the app is as follows. It's an app that is going to be rolled out to various companies all in the same industry. Each company has something called company options, this is a way of tayloring the app to each company. So when you first install the app, a company id is entered and the webservice gets that company's options. The app then behaves in a bespoken way. Can i not use company options in this way. The app has maybe 15 activities which read these options so i need a way of setting variables globally

Comment: The issues I have seen were during stress test and may not cause "real" problems. Especially in your case since you don't change the value of the shared preference. However, I would only use a shared preference to store state locally between executions. You may consider the alternative to store these settings in a custom application object instead. That is easily accessible from all activities.

Comment: ok, i thought that is point of sharedpreferences, to share data in an application scope way? A shared preference is accessible from anywhere in the app is it not?

Comment: Yes, it is. But often there are better ways to share with an app during its life time. The issue I saw was some versions ago (GB I think), so it can be resolved by now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your two last calls to `getString()` in `onCreate()` are returning null because your AsyncTask has not yet finished. That's the asynchronous nature of multithreading and so you have to account for that. First of all I would move:

```
 String isSavePassword = appSharedPrefs.getString("20", null);
 isAllowChangeUser = appSharedPrefs.getString("30", null);
```

into the `onPostExecute()` of your AsyncTask. And then I would account for them being null in whichever case they were to be used, display a dialog that they the app is not yet ready or deactive a button somewhere.